# What does the sparkle next to a monsters name mean?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-3

In the early parts of the game, I encountered some monsters with sparkles next their name and level. Some monsters have them and some monsters do not (including monsters of the same species in the same area).

What do the sparkles indicate?

[image: monster with sparkly name]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you see an enemy or monster with these sparks, you have located a **Lucky monster**. Lucky monsters are rare, but their strength isn’t any different than the rest of their types.

Lucky monsters will give out far better rewards when they are defeated. If a particular type of enemy is a Lucky monster, you’re **far more likely to earn legendary versions of their materials or unique equipment** for your characters.

[image: ingame tutorial on lucky monsters]

According to [Gamepur](https://www.gamepur.com/guides/why-do-some-enemies-have-sparkling-names-in-xenoblade-chronicles-3-answered).

Comment: I’m curious on the rarity of it though. I found quite a few of them

Comment: @Wondercricket They aren't as rare as you might expect if you are thinking of them like shiny Pokemon or something.  They also seem consistent, meaning when monsters respawn, the "lucky" ones will be in the same places, same as normal and Elite versions.